# How to get a button below a scrollingtext view?

Tags: android, xml

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
    android:text="@string/large_text3" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text="How to form the genitive case"
```

//  I want to get a button below my scrolling textview, but it keeps crashing and wont show in design, neither can I make a button in design when I try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a [ViewGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup), which is what organizes views in a layout.

For you case, a [LinearLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout), which is a type of ViewGroup, would suffice.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
        android:text="@string/large_text3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="How to form the genitive case"/>
</LinearLayout>
```